# MySQL get count as percentage

Tags: mysql

**regions**

```
id  | name
-------------------
1   | NY
2   | Paris
3   | London
```

**restaurants**

```
Restaurant_id   | name      | region_id
-------------------------------------------
1               | KFC       | 1
2               | McDonals  | 1
3               | La food   | 2
```

**restaurant_items**

```
id  | top_image | proffesional_photo | is_lunch | is_dinner | is_beverage | restaurant_id
---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
1   |default.png| nulll              | false    | false     | false       | 1
2   |default.png| null               | true     | true      | true        | 1
3   |mypic.png  | pic1.png           | false    | false     | false       | 1
4   |default.png| null               | true     | true      | true        | 2
5   |yoyo.png   | nulll              | false    | false     | false       | 2
6   |default.png| some.png           | true     | true      | true        | 3
7   |default.png| another.png        | false    | false     | false       | 3
8   |default.png| new.png            | false    | false     | false       | 3
```

By these three tables, I want to generate a report like this

```
location | number_of_restaurants | total dishes | percentage_of_pro_pics | percentage_of_top_pics | percentage_of_tagged
------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
NY       | 2             | 5        | 20%            | 40%                    | 40%
Paris    | 1             | 3        | 100%           | 0%                     | 33.33%
NY       | 0             | 0        | null           | null                   | null
```

If I explain the columns,

> percentage_of_pro_pics = count(proffesional_photo IS NOT NULL) / total
>   dishes * 100
>
> percentage_of_top_pics = count(top_image != 'default.png') / total
>   dishes * 100
>
> percentage_of_tagged = count(is_lunch = true OR is_dinner = true OR
>   is_beverage = true)
>   * Here atleast one column from three columns should be true.

```
SELECT regions.name,count(distinct restaurants.Restaurant_id),
count(distinct restaurant_items.id)
 FROM test2.restaurant_items
left join restaurants on restaurant_items.restaurant_id = restaurants.Restaurant_id
left join regions on restaurants.region_id = regions.id
group by regions.name;
```

But I don't know how to implement last three on them.

Comment: What version of MySQL are you using?

Comment: @Nick Server version: 5.7.25-0ubuntu0.18.04.2 (Ubuntu)

Answer (score 0):

use `case when expression`

```
SELECT regions.name,
       count(distinct restaurants.Restaurant_id),
       count(distinct restaurant_items.id),
       (count(case when proffesional_photo IS NOT NULL then 1 end)*100.00)/
ISNULL(NULLIF(count(distinct restaurant_items.id),0), 1) as pro_pics_percentage,
       (count(case when top_image != 'default.png' then 1 end)*100.00)/
ISNULL(NULLIF(count(distinct restaurant_items.id),0), 1) as top_pics_percentage,
       (count(case when is_lunch = true OR is_dinner = true OR is_beverage = true then 1 end)*100.00)/
ISNULL(NULLIF(count(distinct restaurant_items.id),0), 1) as tagged_percentage
FROM test2.restaurant_items
left join restaurants on restaurant_items.restaurant_id = restaurants.Restaurant_id
left join regions on restaurants.region_id = regions.id
group by regions.name
```

Answer (score 0):

This query will give you the results you want. It uses a derived table to get the number of professional pics, top pics and tagged items for each restaurant, and then `JOIN`s that to the regions and restaurants. In the outer query the SUM of each field (e.g. top pics) is divided by the total number of dishes to get the required percentages:

```
SELECT rg.name AS location,
       COUNT(r.restaurant_id) AS num_restaurants,
       SUM(total_dishes),
       SUM(pro_pics) / SUM(total_dishes) * 100 AS percent_pro_pics,
       SUM(top_pics) / SUM(total_dishes) * 100 AS percent_top_pics,
       SUM(tagged) / SUM(total_dishes) * 100 AS percent_tagged
FROM regions rg
LEFT JOIN restaurants r ON r.region_id = rg.id
LEFT JOIN (SELECT restaurant_id,
                  COUNT(id) AS total_dishes AS total_dishes,
                  COUNT(proffesional_photo) AS pro_pics,
                  SUM(top_image != 'default.png') AS top_pics,
                  SUM((is_lunch = 'true') + (is_dinner = 'true') + (is_beverage = 'true') > 0) AS tagged
           FROM restaurant_items
           GROUP BY restaurant_id) ri ON ri.restaurant_id = r.restaurant_id
GROUP BY location
ORDER BY num_restaurants DESC
```

Output:

```
location    num_restaurants total_dishes    percent_pro_pics    percent_top_pics    percent_tagged
NY          2               5               20                  40                  40
Paris       1               3               100                 0                   33.3333
London      0               null            null                null                null
```

[Demo on dbfiddle](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/6pkq61NEFKMdvkZKdTNLp4/1)